# What's the number in SQLite query plan mean?

Tags: sqlite, sql-execution-plan

I output the query plan on SQLite, and it shows

```
 0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t (~500000 rows)
```

I wonder what is the meaning of the number (500000)? I guess it is the table length, but I executed the query on a small table which does not have so many rows.

Is there any official document about the meaning of the number? thanks.

Comment: Isn't the [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) clear enough? Please add the query you are executing here.

Comment: @fpietka No, it is not clear. The web page has 'The example above shows SQLite estimating that the full-table scan will visit approximately 100,000 records.' but there is no example above say anything about the number of 100,000. Importantly, I want to know how the 100,000 is obtained, why it does not same with real table length.

Comment: What is the query? also what is your table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) says, this is the number of rows that the database *estimates* will be returned.

If there is an index on a seached column, and if you have run [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html), then SQLite can make an estimate based on the actual data. Otherwise, it assumes that tables contain one million rows, and that a search like `column > x` filters out half the rows.

Comment: Indeed, I have run ANALYZE before EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN. However, the row number (500000) is obviously too much greater than the actual row number (about 20). I wonder how the the query plan do the estimation ? thanks. @CL.

Comment: Without an index, there is not much information (but without an index, not many optimizations are possible anyway).